# Some calculus in the orthogonal group $O(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, haar-measure

How  can one compute each of the following  matrices, explicitly:

$$\int_{O(n)} e^{g}dg$$ or
$$\int_{O(n)} g^{n}dg \;\;\;\;n\in \mathbb{N} \;\;n>1$$
What is the  explicite entries of the resulting matrices, for $n=2$?

Moreover, for $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}$ define the linear operator $T_{n,m}$ on $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ as follow:
$$T_{n,m}(A)=\int_{O(n)}g^{n}Ag^{m}$$
Under what suficcient and  necessary condition, $T_{n,m}$ is  conjugate to $T_{n',m'}$? Is there an explicit formulation for $T_{n,m}$?

The integration is based on the Haar measear  defined on orthogonal group $O(n)$.

Comment: since the first two integrals are proportional to the unit matrix, you can take the trace to find the coefficient of proportionality and then use theorem 4 from http://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/random_matrices.pdf

Comment: @CarloBeenakker why these are scalar matrices?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thanks very much for the link paper.

Comment: The first two integrals are invariant under automorphisms of $O(n)$, so in particular under conjugation, so must be multiples of the identity by Schur's lemma.

Comment: The key phrase is "higher Frobenius-Schur indicators" --- these can be computed from http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0021869307003420/1-s2.0-S0021869307003420-main.pdf?_tid=5fb7bb40-a872-11e4-8c73-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1422617171_0a6df2ad1d761ab92c7f0e93cf5c3bad , I believe. Unfortunately if I remember right Diaconis et al. need $n$ to be large in terms of the power, but the two combined should likely give you what you need (sorry for not helping much! --- I'm in a bit of a rush now).

Comment: @alpoge --- the condition on $n$ from Diaconis and Shahshahani was corrected in a later paper by Diaconis and Evans; I have edited my answer, hopefully I got it right this time.

Comment: Oh cool! I hadn't seen that paper. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

let me work out the comments a bit further, starting from the identity (equation 8.2 from [Diaconis and Evans](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/functionals.pdf), correcting an earlier [paper](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/random_matrices.pdf) by Diaconis and Shahshahani)

$$\int_{{\rm O}(n)}{\rm tr}\,g^p\,dg=\begin{cases}
0&{\rm if}\;\;p\;\;\text{is an odd integer}\\
1&{\rm if}\;\;p\;\;\text{is an even integer}
\end{cases}
$$

so the second integral of the OP evaluates to
$$\int_{{\rm O}(n)}g^p\,dg=\begin{cases}
0&{\rm if}\;\;p\;\;\text{is an odd integer}\\
n^{-1}\mathbb{1}&{\rm if}\;\;p\;\;\text{is an even integer}
\end{cases}
$$

Taylor expansion of the exponent in the first integral of the OP and term-by-term integration gives
$$
\int_{{\rm O}(n)}e^g\,dg=n^{-1}\mathbb{1}\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2p)!}=\frac{\cosh 1}{n}\mathbb{1}
$$

now for the third integral of the OP, we need the fourth-order tensor
$$\int_{{\rm O}(n)}(g^p)_{ij}(g^q)_{kl}\,dg=a_{pq}(n)\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}+b_{pq}(n)\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}+c_{pq}(n)\delta_{il}\delta_{jk}$$
so that the required integral takes the form
$$\int_{{\rm O}(n)}g^p Ag^q\,dg=a_{pq}(n)A+b_{pq}(n)A^{\rm t}+c_{pq}(n)\mathbb{1}\,{\rm tr}\,A
$$
by taking traces I find, using again equation 8.2 from [Diaconis and Evans](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/functionals.pdf), that
$$na_{pq}(n)+nb_{pq}(n)+n^2 c_{pq}(n)=\int_{{\rm O}(n)}{\rm tr}\,g^{p+q}\,dg=\begin{cases}
0&{\rm if}\;\;p+q\;\;\text{is an odd integer}\\
1&{\rm if}\;\;p+q\;\;\text{is an even integer}
\end{cases}
$$
$$n^2a_{pq}(n)+nb_{pq}(n)+nc_{pq}(n)=\int_{{\rm O}(n)}({\rm tr}\,g^p)({\rm tr}\,g^q)\,dg=\begin{cases}
{\rm min}\,(p,2n)&{\rm if}\;\;p=q\;\;{\rm odd}\\
{\rm min}\,(p,2n)+1&{\rm if}\;\;p=q\;\;{\rm even}\\
1&{\rm if}\;\;p\neq q\;\;\text{both even}\\
0&{\rm otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
$$na_{pq}(n)+n^2 b_{pq}(n)+nc_{pq}(n)=\int_{{\rm O}(n)}{\rm tr}\,g^{|p-q|}\,dg=\begin{cases}
0&{\rm if}\;\;p+q\;\;\text{is an odd integer}\\
1&{\rm if}\;\;p+q\;\;\text{is an even integer}
\end{cases}
$$
Three equations with three unknowns solves the third integral.

Comment: Why do the complex eigenvalues average out to 0?

Comment: @WillSawin --- good point, this is not obvious, so I have removed the "simple argument", which was apparently too simple; for the record, it follows after this comment. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: deleted "simplistic argument" for the first integral in my answer: the result for $p$ odd is obvious because contributions $\pm g$ to the integral cancel; the result for $p$ even follows without calculation from the fact that only eigenvalues $\pm 1$ of the orthogonal matrix $g$ contribute to the average of the trace (the complex eigenvalues average out to zero); for $n$ odd every $g$ has one such eigenvalue, so the average is one, for $n$ even and ${\rm det}\,g=+1$ there are no such eigenvalues but for ${\rm det}\,g=-1$ there are two, so the average is again one.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thank you very much for your very interesting answer.